MSSQL Parsing JSON file with OPENJSON issue
So I'm trying tp parse a JSON file with nested elements but I can't seem to get to the 'Deeper' elements within the file.  I tried using the examples from the MS site on the OPENJSON syntax and examples page but to no avail.
Below is the sample JSON and the code
Sample JSON:
{
"createdDate": 1709325679871, 
"orderNumber": "24-TX-EK-1101", 
"estimatedClosing": 1710954000000, 
"purchasePrice": "167,702.00", 
"status": "CANCELLED", 
"disbursementDate": 1710954000000, 
"transactionType": "EK-Single File Purchase", 
"charges": 
  [{"lineNumber": "1310", 
  "payeeName": "SnapDocs", 
  "section": "Additional Charges", 
  "sellerAmount": 
  {
     "total": "94.95"
  }, 
  "borrowerAmount": 
  {
     "total": null
     }
  }, 
  {"lineNumber": "1309", 
  "payeeName": "Robertson Anschutz Vetters, LLC", 
  "section": "Additional Charges", 
  "sellerAmount": 
  {
     "total": "100.00"
  }, 
  "borrowerAmount": 
  {
     "total": null
   }
}
   ], 
  "accounting": 
  {
     "disbursements": []
  }, 
  "loans": 
     [{
        "amount": "134,160.00"
     }], 
  "properties": 
     [{
        "address1": "604 19th Avenue North", 
        "state": "TX"
     }]}

Sample TSQL:
Declare @JSON2 varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON2=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\admin_tftitle\Documents\ENT API\charges_all.JSON', 
SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON2)
WITH 
(
 [createdDate] varchar(max),
[orderNumber] varchar(max), 
[estimatedClosing] varchar(100),
[purchasePrice] varchar(100),
[status] varchar(100),
[disbursementDate] varchar(100),
[transactionType] varchar(100),
charges nvarchar(MAX) N'$.charges' AS JSON,
lineNumber nvarchar(max) N'$.charges.lineNumber',
accounting nvarchar(MAX) N'$.accounting' AS JSON,
loans nvarchar(MAX) N'$.loans' AS JSON,
properties nvarchar(MAX) N'$.properties' AS JSON
 )

The issue is with the [lineNumber] column. No matter what I do I keep getting a NULL for it and other elements within the 'charges' section.  Everything else works fine, including the AS JSON columns.
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated
